# Vector of structures is causing file.exe to stop working

Tags: vector, structure

I'm trying to create a dynamic array of pointers to structure objects.  I have done this before, but never really understood it, so I'm lost now that it's failing.

My code is:

```
struct object {
    char* alias;
    char* mapInfo;
    char* binaryData;
};

class ATP
{
public:
    ATP();
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<object>> objects;
};
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to run it it says

"ATPEditor.exe has stopped working.  A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.  Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

I'm not trying to use anything like a `push_back` yet, I'm just trying to create the array.

Does anyone know why this is failing?  Or if there is somewhere else I might have made a mistake?

EDIT: When copying the rest of my code into this window, I noticed that I had mistyped the constructor.  Once I fixed it the problem went away.  Thanks.

Comment: How can you run it? There's no `main()` function.

Comment: I have a main.cpp file that creates an ATP object
<code>ATP atp1();</code>

Comment: Can you post it so we can try compiling it, to see if we can reproduce the problem?